# FFMPEG throwing errors in Linux VPS but working fine with WINDOWS

Tags: ffmpeg

I am quite new to scripting so please excuse my lack of knowledge and i am learning.

I have a project and trying to install a script. Its called Tilacam from Github. When i run this script this on Windows FFMPEG it seems its working, but when i run it off VPS Linux Debian the ffmpeg section stops working.

On the config.php this is whats required;

```
$config_pathToFFmpeg = 'C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe';
```

I call ffmpeg in linux like this

```
$config_pathToFFmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';
```

However, theres a test page which identifies if script is creating a movie. This is what we get `ffmpeg -f image2 -r 25 -i "/var/www/html/timelapse/tilacam/video/%05d.jpg" -vcodec libx264 -b 5000k -tune stillimage "/var/www/html/timelapse/tilacam/video/video_all.mp4"`

We get this error `Could find no file with path '/var/www/html/timelapse/tilacam/video/%05d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4 /var/www/html/timelapse/tilacam/video/%05d.jpg: No such file or directory`

I am really getting stuck and do not know how to fix this!

Can someone please help?

Matt

Comment: Just to make sure, have you verified you have at least one of '00000.jpg', '00001.jpg', '00002.jpg', '00003.jpg', or '00004.jpg' is indeed present in `/var/www/html/timelapse/tilacam/video/` directory? This type of error is usually not an FFmpeg issue. Also, check and make sure the read permissions of these files are properly set.

Comment: Kesh thank you for your input. However, in the folder i only have `20220213120001.jpg` - a date format from an IP camera

Comment: That's the problem. With your specification `%05d.jpg` FFmpeg is expecting JPG files with 5 digits followed by '.jpg'. In addition, the first file must be `00004.jpg` or less. So, what you need to do is to find a way to batch-rename your files before sending them to FFmpeg.

Comment: Here is [the documentation on `image2` format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) if you haven't read it already.

Comment: Started to write my recommendation but check [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/1661735) out. If renaming your files is too cumbersome or undesirable, you can try `-f image2 -pattern_type glob` or `-f concat` (the latter with a text file with the list of all the JPG files). Hope this link helps.

Comment: Thank you Kesh! So the FFMPEG windows v Linux is usually same right?

Comment: For the most part yes, I cannot remember off the top of my head right now, but there is one issue that keeps popping up here that works in one but not on the other though. So, yes, "usually" is the right word.

Comment: Actually, `-pattern_type glob` may not work in Windows as `glob` is a Linux command. So, if you need interop, `concat` might be the right way to go.

Comment: So i've looked into command, this is what i have;       `$command = $config_pathToFFmpeg.' -f image2 -r 25 -i "'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$config_videoDir.'/'.$this->picturePrefix.'_%05d.jpg" -vcodec libx264 -b 5000k -tune stillimage "'.$outputFile.'"'; `
'